# Передать данные с формы в виде объекта в контроллер ASP.NET 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

**Пробую ASP.NET 5 или ASP.NET core 1.0**

Так выглядит форма:

```
@model WebApplication2.ViewModels.ViewPost

<form asp-controller="home" asp-action="AddPost" method="post" role="form">
    @Html.EditorForModel(Model)
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

Так выглядит контроллер:

```
[HttpPost]       
public IActionResult AddPost(ViewPost post)
{
    return Content($"Name: {post.name} Post: {post.post}");
}
```

Так выглядит модель ViewPost:

```
public class ViewPost
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string post { get; set; }
    }
```

**В конечном итоге свойства модели контроллер вообще не получает, проверил дебаггером.**

А если изменить контроллер так:

```
[HttpPost]       
        public IActionResult AddPost(string name, string post)
        {
            return Content($"Name: {name} Post: {post}");

        }
```

то все работает, что я упустил ?
Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: а если переименовать AddPost(ViewPost model) и в самой моделе поле post переимновать в detail или ещё как?

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, а почему так ?

Comment: зарезервированные слова

Comment: @Konst: Замена `ViewPost model` на `ViewPost post` - решение проблемы. Переименования поля модели не требуется. Почему бы Вам не написать ответ с этой информацией? Мне кажется, стоит.

Comment: @Georgeeeb: [Страница MVC документации о model binding](http://docs.asp.net/projects/mvc/en/latest/models/model-binding.html) скоро будет опубликована. См. предварительую версию [здесь](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/pull/933)

Answer (score 1):

Решение:

```
[HttpPost]       
public IActionResult AddPost(ViewPost model)
{
    return Content($"Name: {model.name} Post: {model.post}");
}
```

т.е замена `ViewPost post` на `ViewPost model`